# Cannot resolve keyword 'Pelicula' into field. Choices are: ano_nacimiento, id, imagen, nacionalidad, nombre, pelicula, resumen_biografico

Tags: python, django

mi programa bien, pero comenzo a lanzar este error y no entiendo que esta pasando. cuando intento abrir un nuevo template, surge este error "Cannot resolve keyword 'Pelicula' into field. Choices are: ano_nacimiento, id, imagen, nacionalidad, nombre, pelicula, resumen_biografico".

les muestro el codigo

MODELOS

```
 class Pelicula(models.Model):
    objects=PeliculaManager()
    titulo=models.CharField(max_length=70, null=False)
    imagen=models.ImageField(upload_to='peliculas/')
    puntaje=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    actores=models.ManyToManyField(Actores)
    director=models.ForeignKey(Director, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ano=models.DateField()
    resumen=models.CharField(max_length=800)

    def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s %s'%(self.titulo,self.director,self.actores)

 class Actores (models.Model):
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imagen=models.ImageField(upload_to='actores/')
    nacionalidad= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ano_nacimiento=models.DateField()
    resumen_biografico=models.TextField(max_length=800)
     
    class Meta:
     verbose_name = ("Actor")
     verbose_name_plural = ("Actores")
    

    def __str__(self):
      return self.nombre

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

VISTAS

```
 class PeliculasView(View):
  template_name = 'PeliculasInfo.html'
  form_class = criticaForm()

def get(self, request, pk):  # Implementa el metodo get, le pasas el pk como parametro que 
    declaras en el path de tu url
    context = {
        'pelicula': Pelicula.objects.get(pk=pk),
        'Actores': Actores.objects.filter(pelicula=pk),
        'Director': Director.objects.filter(Pelicula=pk),
        'criticas': Critica.objects.filter(pelicula=pk),
        "titulo": "PeliculasWeb 2023 | Informacion",
        'form': self.form_class
    }                    
    return render(request, self.template_name, context) # Returnas el método render que 
    mostrara el contenido del template y el diccionario de contexto.

 

  class Actor(DetailView):
  model= Actores
  template_name="actor.html"


  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
     context['Actores']=Actores.objects.all()
     return context
```

URLS ACLARO QUE EL ERROR ESTA CUANDO LLAMO A LA URL "INFO"

```
  urlpatterns = [
      path("", views.HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
      path("info/<int:pk>/", views.PeliculasView.as_view(), name="info"),
  ]
```

Comment: Fíjate en las mayúsculas y minúsculas que provee el error: `Pelicula` vs `pelicula`

Answer (score 0):

Ese error indica que el modelo Actores no tiene un campo llamado 'Pelicula', por lo que no puede filtrar los actores por ese campo en la vista PeliculasView.

En la línea 'Actores': Actores.objects.filter(pelicula=pk) de la vista PeliculasView, tenés que cambiar 'pelicula' por el nombre del campo adecuado en el modelo Pelicula que se utiliza para relacionarse con el modelo Actores.

MODELOS:

```
class Pelicula(models.Model):
    # Mantuve la llamada a la clase PeliculaManager 
        #porque debe existir en tu código  
    objects = PeliculaManager()
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=False)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='peliculas/')
    puntaje = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    actores = models.ManyToManyField('Actores')
    director = models.ForeignKey('Director', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ano = models.DateField()
    resumen = models.CharField(max_length=800)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.titulo, self.director, self.actores)


class Actores(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='actores/')
    nacionalidad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ano_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    resumen_biografico = models.TextField(max_length=800)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Actor")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Actores")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Agregué el método save para que los objetos puedan ser guardados correctamente en la base de datos
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) 

#Esta clase podes quitarla si ya existe en tu modelo
    #yo la agregué porque era invocada en el código 
class Director(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='directores/')
    nacionalidad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ano_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    resumen_biografico = models.TextField(max_length=800)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Director")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Directores")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Se agrega el método save para que los objetos puedan ser guardados correctamente en la base de datos
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) 


#Esta clase podes quitarla si ya existe en tu modelo
    #yo la agregué porque era invocada en el código
class PeliculaManager(models.Manager):
    def buscar_pelicula(self, query):
        return self.filter(titulo__icontains=query)
```

VISTAS:

```
from django.views.generic import View, DetailView
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Pelicula, Actores, Director

class PeliculasView(View):
    template_name = 'PeliculasInfo.html'
    form_class = criticaForm()

    def get(self, request, pk):
        pelicula = Pelicula.objects.get(pk=pk)
        actores = pelicula.actores.all()
        director = pelicula.director
        criticas = Critica.objects.filter(pelicula=pk)
        context = {
            'pelicula': pelicula,
            'actores': actores,
            'director': director,
            'criticas': criticas,
            'titulo': 'PeliculasWeb 2023 | Informacion',
            'form': self.form_class,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

class Actor(DetailView):
    model = Actores
    template_name = 'actor.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Corregí la capitalización del nombre del campo en el diccionario de contexto
        context['actores'] = Actores.objects.all()
        return context
```

URLS:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomeView, PeliculasView, Actor

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('info/<int:pk>/', PeliculasView.as_view(), name='info'),
    # Agregué una nueva ruta para la vista Actor
    path('actor/<int:pk>/', Actor.as_view(), name='actor'),
]
```